# Using recursion to find all possible permutations of 2 arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Pseudo-code.

```
# Suppose 2 arrays:
a1 = [a,b]
a2 = [x,y]

# Looking to find an array of all possible permutations across 2 elements
# Likely not phrasing this correctly, so here's the desired outcome
  a,x,b,x
  a,x,b,y
  a,y,b,x
  a,y,b,y
  b,x,a,x
  b,x,a,y
  b,y,a,x
  b,y,a,y

# Here's a visualization

      a
    /   \
  x       y
  |       |
  b       b
 / \     / \
x   y   x   y

yields solutions, reading from top tow
  a,x,b,x
  a,x,b,y
  a,y,b,x
  a,y,b,y

repeat with b on top for latter 4 solutions

# Trying to do the code recursively iterating through arrays

def test(a1,a2,outcome = [])
  a1.each do |e|
    if a2.size == 1
      return outcome << e,a2[0]
    else
      test(a2,a1.reject { |a| a == e }, outcome)
    end
  end
end
```

I have no idea how to get the desired outcome.

Comment: Your question is confusing. In the title of your question, you are asking about *combinations*. In the code, you talk about *permutations*. However, permutations and combinations are different things, so which of the two is it? Also, your desired result looks neither like permutations nor like combinations, which just adds to the confusion. And the logic isn't clear either: if you are looking for "all possible" whatever-you-are-looking-for, and duplicating elements is allowed, as we can clearly see in the outputs `a,x,b,x`, `a,y,b,y`, `b,x,a,x`, and `b,y,a,y`, then where did `a,x,a,x`, …

Comment: … `a,x,a,y`, `a,y,a,x`, `a,y,a,y`, `b,x,b,x`, `b,x,b,y`, `b,y,b,x`, and `b,y,b,y` go? Never forget that computers are *very, very dumb*, and *very, very literal*, and they have no creativity, and don't take context into account; they also don't ask clarifying questions. If you cannot even write down what you want to achieve in a way that a *human* can understand it, then you will have no hope in explaining  it to a computer!

Comment: thanks tried to clarify!

Comment: That's essentially the product of each element of `a1` with `a2` and then again the resulting product of those two products: `x, y = a1.map {|el| [el].product(a2)}; x.product(y)`.

Comment: `a1 = [a,b]` references two variables or methods whose values are not known: `a` and `b`. If you mean those to be literals you need to write something like `a1 = ['a','b']` or `a1 = [:a,:b]`. At heart, it's an interesting question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : If I remember correctly, this is called _cross product_ in set theory. Of course the OP does not have sets here, but arrays, but the idea is sufficiently close that cross product should be a good description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def moment_of_truth(a1, a2)
  (a1.permutation(2).to_a).product(a2.repeated_permutation(2).to_a).
    map { |(e1, e2), (f1, f2)| [e1, f1, e2, f2 ] }
end
```

```
moment_of_truth(['a', 'b'], ['x', 'y'])
  #=> [["a", "x", "b", "x"], ["a", "x", "b", "y"], ["a", "y", "b", "x"],
  #    ["a", "y", "b", "y"], ["b", "x", "a", "x"], ["b", "x", "a", "y"],
  #    ["b", "y", "a", "x"], ["b", "y", "a", "y"]]
```

```
moment_of_truth(['a', 'b'], ['x', 'y', 'z'])
  #=> [["a", "x", "b", "x"], ["a", "x", "b", "y"], ["a", "x", "b", "z"],
  #    ["a", "y", "b", "x"], ["a", "y", "b", "y"], ["a", "y", "b", "z"],
  #    ["a", "z", "b", "x"], ["a", "z", "b", "y"], ["a", "z", "b", "z"],
  #    ["b", "x", "a", "x"], ["b", "x", "a", "y"], ["b", "x", "a", "z"],
  #    ["b", "y", "a", "x"], ["b", "y", "a", "y"], ["b", "y", "a", "z"],
  #    ["b", "z", "a", "x"], ["b", "z", "a", "y"], ["b", "z", "a", "z"]]
```

```
moment_of_truth(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y'])
  #=> [["a", "x", "b", "x"], ["a", "x", "b", "y"], ["a", "y", "b", "x"],
  #    ["a", "y", "b", "y"], ["a", "x", "c", "x"], ["a", "x", "c", "y"],
  #    ["a", "y", "c", "x"], ["a", "y", "c", "y"], ["b", "x", "a", "x"],
  #    ["b", "x", "a", "y"], ["b", "y", "a", "x"], ["b", "y", "a", "y"],
  #    ["b", "x", "c", "x"], ["b", "x", "c", "y"], ["b", "y", "c", "x"],
  #    ["b", "y", "c", "y"], ["c", "x", "a", "x"], ["c", "x", "a", "y"],
  #    ["c", "y", "a", "x"], ["c", "y", "a", "y"], ["c", "x", "b", "x"],
  #    ["c", "x", "b", "y"], ["c", "y", "b", "x"], ["c", "y", "b", "y"]]
```

```
moment_of_truth(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']) 
  #=> [["a", "x", "b", "x"], ["a", "x", "b", "y"], ["a", "x", "b", "z"],
  #    ["a", "y", "b", "x"], ["a", "y", "b", "y"], ["a", "y", "b", "z"],
  #    ["a", "z", "b", "x"], ["a", "z", "b", "y"], ["a", "z", "b", "z"],
  #    ["a", "x", "c", "x"], ["a", "x", "c", "y"], ["a", "x", "c", "z"],
  #    ["a", "y", "c", "x"], ["a", "y", "c", "y"], ["a", "y", "c", "z"],
  #    ["a", "z", "c", "x"], ["a", "z", "c", "y"], ["a", "z", "c", "z"],
  #    ["b", "x", "a", "x"], ["b", "x", "a", "y"], ["b", "x", "a", "z"],
  #    ["b", "y", "a", "x"], ["b", "y", "a", "y"], ["b", "y", "a", "z"],
  #    ["b", "z", "a", "x"], ["b", "z", "a", "y"], ["b", "z", "a", "z"],
  #    ["b", "x", "c", "x"], ["b", "x", "c", "y"], ["b", "x", "c", "z"],
  #    ["b", "y", "c", "x"], ["b", "y", "c", "y"], ["b", "y", "c", "z"],
  #    ["b", "z", "c", "x"], ["b", "z", "c", "y"], ["b", "z", "c", "z"],
  #    ["c", "x", "a", "x"], ["c", "x", "a", "y"], ["c", "x", "a", "z"],
  #    ["c", "y", "a", "x"], ["c", "y", "a", "y"], ["c", "y", "a", "z"],
  #    ["c", "z", "a", "x"], ["c", "z", "a", "y"], ["c", "z", "a", "z"],
  #    ["c", "x", "b", "x"], ["c", "x", "b", "y"], ["c", "x", "b", "z"],
  #    ["c", "y", "b", "x"], ["c", "y", "b", "y"], ["c", "y", "b", "z"],
  #    ["c", "z", "b", "x"], ["c", "z", "b", "y"], ["c", "z", "b", "z"]]

moment_of_truth(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a']) # returns 192 arrays
  #=> [["a", "x", "b", "x"], ["a", "x", "b", "y"], ["a", "x", "b", "z"],
  #    ["a", "x", "b", "a"], ["a", "y", "b", "x"], ["a", "y", "b", "y"],
  #    ["a", "y", "b", "z"], ["a", "y", "b", "a"], ["a", "z", "b", "x"],
  #    ...
  #    ["d", "a", "c", "y"], ["d", "a", "c", "z"], ["d", "a", "c", "a"]]
```

See [Array#permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation), [Array#repeated_permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) and [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product).

Note that because of the asymmetry between how `a1` and `a2` are treated, no guidance has been provided for how the addition of one more arrays (e.g., `a1`, `a2` and `a3`) should be treated, so I have not addressed that case.

I don't see how recursion can be used here, but perhaps a reader can prove me wrong.

Comment: is a recursive solution possible?

Comment: james, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the product of each element of `a1` with `a2`:

- `[:a]` × `a2`
- `[:b]` × `a2`

And then again the product of those two products.

We can express that in Ruby almost exactly like we express it in English:

```ruby
x, y = a1.map {|el| [el].product(a2) }
(x.product(y) + y.product(x)).map(&:flatten)
```

This code not only solves your problem, it even solves the *more general* problem where `a1` and `a2` have an *arbitrary number* of elements.

Comment: yes thank you that semantically is better! question though, is there not a way to do this with a recursion that i was trying to start? i am working on an exercise in recursion and specifically trying to do it that way

Comment: That solves the given problem, but does not generalize. For example, if `a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and `a2 = ['x', 'y', 'z']`, none of the elements of the array returned (each a 4-element array) begins with `'c'`: `x, y = a1.map {|el| [el].product(a2) }
(x.product(y) + y.product(x)).map(&:flatten).map(&:first).uniq #=> ["a", "b"]`.